# bootstrap navbar is not working properly for Laravel, only a part is working

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, navbar, laravel-blade

I created a navbar from bootstrap inside resources/views/inc -> navbar.blade.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Project</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

The first div tag is working fine but the second div tag is not visible in the output

And I properly include the navbar in a separate file inside resources/views/layouts -> app.blade.php

```
<body>
    @include('inc.navbar')
    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')   
    </div>
</body>
```

Please help me with this

### edit

I removed `class="collapse navbar-collapse"`, then the navigation links are appearing, what is the issue with the compatibility on the `collapse`?

Comment: Sorry, which div is not visible?  The navbar-header or the id="navbar"?

Comment: ` <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">` this isn't visible

Comment: That's correct for a collapse menu - see my answer.  I think it is working properly :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to wanting this div to be visible immediately (without clicking):

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">...</div>
```

As it is, it is not meant to be visible upon load.  If you want it to load, you've got an extra collapse class in there, which is effectively hiding the div, remove it, and it should be visible for you:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse"> <-- No collapse
```

Comment: it is similar to the edit, I tried without any class to the given Div tag.

Comment: Yes.  This is the expected behaviour.  I believe this answers your original question, no?

Comment: I need to check my CSS to see the issue , then I'll accept your answer